# UPDATE or INSERT INTO is not working in procedure?

Tags: sql, firebird, flamerobin

Table `Attendance`:

```
EMPL_KODE |EMPL_NAME  |DATE_IN    |TIME_IN |TIME_OUT|TOTAL_MIN |TOTAL_HOUR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    001   | Michel    |25.04.2016 |06:50   |15:40   |NULL      |NULL
    002   | Clara     |25.04.2016 |06:15   |15:43   |NULL      |NULL
    003   | Rafael    |25.04.2016 |06:25   |15:45   |NULL      |NULL
    001   | Michel    |26.04.2016 |06:23   |15:42   |NULL      |NULL
    002   | Clara     |26.04.2016 |06:10   |15:41   |NULL      |NULL
    003   | Rafael    |26.04.2016 |06:30   |15:42   |NULL      |NULL
    001   | Michel    |27.04.2016 |06:33   |15:42   |NULL      |NULL
    002   | Clara     |27.04.2016 |06:54   |15:44   |NULL      |NULL
    003   | Rafael    |27.04.2016 |07:00   |15:45   |NULL      |NULL
```

I've success to create procedure to insert value automatically for column `TOTAL_MIN` and `TOTAL_HOUR` with this syntax :

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATEEMPLOYEES
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE EMPL_KODE CHAR(5);
DECLARE VARIABLE EMPL_NAME VARCHAR (25);
DECLARE VARIABLE TIME_IN TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE VARIABLE TIME_OUT TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE VARIABLE TOTAL_MINUTES INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE TOTAL_HOURS FLOAT;

BEGIN 
FOR SELECT e.EMPL_KODE, e.EMPL_NAME,
       CAST(a.DATE_IN + a.TIME_IN AS TIMESTAMP),
       CAST(a.DATE_IN + a.TIME_OUT AS TIMESTAMP),
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a.TIME_IN,a.TIME_OUT),
       DATEDIFF(HOUR,a.TIME_IN,a.TIME_OUT)
       FROM EMPLOYEE e
       JOIN ATTENDANCE a
       ON e.EMPL_KODE=a.EMPL_KODE

INTO :EMPL_KODE,:EMPL_NAME,:TIME_IN,:TIME_OUT,TOTAL_MINUTES,TOTAL_HOURS
DO
       UPDATE ATTENDANCE a
       set a.TOTAL_MINUTES=:TOTAL_MINUTES,
       a.TOTAL_HOURS=:TOTAL_HOURS
       WHERE a.EMPL_KODE=:EMPL_KODE;

end^
SET TERM ; ^
```

But, the problem is how can I write the syntax directly with `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` ? I've tried but still not working.

I write the code same as the Firebird instruction.

```
   UPDATE OR INSERT INTO
   {tablename | viewname} [(<columns>)]
   VALUES (<values>)
   [MATCHING (<columns>)]
   [RETURNING <values> [INTO <variables>]]

<columns>      ::=  colname  [, colname  ...]
<values>       ::=  value    [, value    ...]
<variables>    ::=  :varname [, :varname ...]
```

Here is my code:

I'm not write the `Returning` because I don't understand what it is.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE BLABLA(
    TOTAL_M INTEGER,
    TOTAL_H FLOAT)
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE or INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (TOTAL_MINUTES,TOTAL_HOURS)
    VALUES (:TOTAL_M,:TOTAL_H)
    MATCHING (EMPL_KODE);
end^
SET TERM ; ^
```

After I commit the statement, it shows the error message :

> UPDATE OR INSERT field list does not match MATCHING clause

What should I do ?

Comment: firebird has also a [MERGE INTO](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-merge.html) DML statement for upserts.

Comment: See the answer of ain for your direct problem, however I don't think your current `update or insert` is precise enough based on the table you show at the start of your question; I would expect the column list, values list and matching list to also include the column `DATE_IN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've got the answer from this http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq336

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATEEMPLOYEEES
AS
begin
UPDATE ATTANDENCE
SET TOTAL_MINUTES=DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TIME_IN,TIME_OUT),
    TOTAL_HOURS=DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TIME_IN,TIME_OUT)/60.0;
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have `MATCHING (EMPL_KODE)` but you don't list the `EMPL_KODE` column in values list - how do you expect the engine to figure out which rows to update? Try something like:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE BLABLA(
    E_KODE CHAR(5),
    TOTAL_M INTEGER,
    TOTAL_H FLOAT)
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE or INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (TOTAL_MINUTES,TOTAL_HOURS, EMPL_KODE)
    VALUES (:TOTAL_M,:TOTAL_H, :E_KODE)
    MATCHING (EMPL_KODE);
end^
SET TERM ; ^
```